# How do I use jquery to validate an input field on change?

Tags: jquery, input, validation, onchange, blur

I have an `input` field:

```
<input type="text" name="notifyEmail" id="parametersEmail" value="" size=40 />
```

I have a chunk of jquery code that works when I hit tab or otherwise leave the field, which calls a validation routine:

```
$("#parametersEmail").blur(function(event) {
    validateParameterEmail();
});
```

What I would like to do is run the `validateParameterEmail()` function whenever the value or content of the input field changes.

So I then also tried the `.change()` handler:

```
$("#parametersEmail").change(function(event) {
    validateParameterEmail();
});
```

But when I change the contents of `parametersEmail`, this handler does not call the validation function.

Is there another handler I should be using, instead? Or can I not attach multiple event handlers to the input field?

Comment: fyi... on an input text field, .blur() and .change() are pretty much effectively the same thing.  The difference is blur = lose focus while change = lose focus + different value.  Point being you have to lose focus on it either way.  If you're wanting the function to be called every time a user enters a char, as they are entering, then use the .keyup or .keydown as mentioned by others

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `$("#parametersEmail").keydown(function(event) {})`

Comment: `.keydown()` appears to actually fire before the value of the input has changed.  In other words, if you type `1234`, this would validate on `123`. Similarly, if you type `1234[delete]`, it would validate on `1234`. `.keyup()` is probably better for form validation.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
$("#parametersEmail").bind('blur', function(event) {} );
```

and

```
$("#parametersEmail").bind('keyup', function(event) {} );
```

Answer (score 4):

> ( Reality on almost 2017-th year )

The best way is to set once the callback on all need events about input value changing.

There are:

- keyup : user typed something in the input
- change : common known method about stored changes in input
- click : some inputs take changes by mouse too
- paste : Yea! Ctrl+V, Crtl+Ins, RightMouseButton+Paste can change input value too
- propertychange : when some JS changes our input at any way, this event will fired
- input : new standard's event that supports all modern browsers, use it too

So, we can set all of them once:

```
$("#parametersEmail").bind("propertychange change click keyup input paste", function(event) {
    validateParameterEmail();
});
```

Hope this helps for someone. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Change refers to when you click away/move from the input. You *may* be looking for `onKeyUp()`.